# Access - Pivoting/Combining Fields for Analysis

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, tableau-api

I am an experienced Excel VBA developer and am putting together a database in Access to structure my data and allow it to properly be fed into an analytic tool (Tableau). The flat file created from multiple data sources via Excel VBA ultimately was not flexible enough to be used for robust analytics, so instead I am building the structure in Access and writing queries to drive each way of looking at the data. I am new to SQL and am trying to learn to use it the "right" way rather than resorting to VBA to do everything.

My question relates to combining multiple records with many fields into a larger number of records with fewer fields. I am recording the date that multiple locations perform a file submission, and they have to submit one file per month. Currently the data is fed into the database like this:

```
Location |         Jan       | Feb | Mar | Apr | etc |
1        | [Submission Date] | ... |     |     |     |
2        | ...               |     |     |     |     |
```

For analytics it seems like it helps to have it like this instead:

```
Location | Month | Submission Date
1        |  Jan  | [Submission Date]
1        |  Feb  | ...
```

How do I restructure the data through a query, or is this even the best way to accomplish this? Although I could easily do this in VBA by itself, I am trying to properly learn when to use SQL and when to use VBA to get things done.

Thanks to everyone in advance, and I am all ears if anyone wants to share some solid resources for building queries, restructuring data, or when to use VBA vs. SQL. So far SQL for me has come across as a hard thing to perform one-off research on.

Comment: You would not normally need your month field, as presumably that is part of the submission date anyway? You can extract that and any other part of the date dynamically, so have no need to store it.

Comment: If your storage has a column per month, I'd argue the database design is flawed and you should look into migrating it to a normalized schema... and  indeed, the month looks like it would be an attribute of the date, so I don't see a need to store it separately/at all. The fact the your source data is denormalized isn't an excuse for loading it as such into your database. Unpivot the data *before* you load it into the table; come query time, it's too late, you've taken the hit (on both storage and performance).

Comment: @Minty, the actual submission date can vary quite a bit. The "Month" field that I am trying to create represents the document, not the submission date. Thanks for sharing your thoughts though.

Comment: @Mat's Mug, I agree completely that the data should come over in another form. Unfortunately the process which creates the input file is a preexisting process that will not be able to be changed. I have to accept the data in this way, and this query is my attempt at properly normalizing the data as it should have been. I could build an Excel VBA macro into the submission process, but this is less desirable as I would like to keep automation inside the tool. I could also revamp the import process in Access with VBA, but I figured queries were more meant to handle this sort of thing. Thoughts?

Comment: I didn't say you need to change the preexisting process, I said you need to add *something* between that process and your database, to normalize the incoming data and *store* it differently. Queries in a relational database work well and efficiently, with *normalized* data. Data will always look like crap, contain crap, and be formatted like crap - that's just how data is. That doesn't mean it needs to be stored that way.

Comment: @Mat's - fixing bad data is an everyday part of the job.  It seems at least as easy to put the fix in the access db as to have some unspecified "other step" between Excel and Access.  IMHO.

Comment: @DonGeorge fixing bad data is the job of an ETL (extract-transfrom-load) process, that takes data in one form and stores that data in another (cleansed/normalized) form. I do that all the time, it just so happens to be my job. Storing bad data and circumventing it at query time will eventually bite you in the rear end, *especially* on a desktop database with limited resources and maximum capacity (beats me why one would pick Access over SQL Server Express, but that's another story). "Oh but it's just a few rows, what does it matter" you'll say - "Famous last words", I'll reply.

Comment: Do you ***want*** fixing bad data to be an everyday part of a job? The entire purpose of a relational database structure and data normalization is to *prevent bad data from happening*.  If you're only loading the data from Excel into Access to query it, structure it in a way that makes that easy and doesn't ***allow*** bad data.  If you really want to work with the bad data, skip Access, query your Excel sheet, and expect as much garbage out as you put in.

Comment: @Mat's Mug - Totally understand that perspective, but can't it get a little hairy when you have a bunch of disparate macros running different import scripts? Not playing devil's advocate - generally want to know, because that is still an option. I have been trying to get away from VBA within instances where using SQL is fundamentally a better choice. My thought was that the next step might simply be turning this into a query which creates/updates a table out of the results. Would you still recommend  a separate ETL process on this small database? And Access was client's requirement, not choice

Comment: @Comintern - No, obviously I don't want fixing bad data to be an everyday part of a job. The question down to the core (as indicated explicitly in the question) is that being new to writing queries, I want to know when should I use a query and when should I use something else. So I take it you also suggest adding a different step which modifies the source data prior it entering a table in the database, correct?

Comment: @jemmell TBH I don't know about Access.. on SQL Server you'd just use *Integration Services* to make a *data flow* from your source to your destination, with all the transform steps in between. SSIS packages are stored in a dedicated SQL Server database, and can be scheduled with SQL Server Agent or executed by hand. With Access... if you can have something like "stored procedures", then you could use that I suppose - i.e. treat the current destination as some "staging" that only contains the unprocessed rows, and then query the normalized tables instead.

Comment: If you need it, yes.  You can either do this before you load the data or you can write a VBA "stored procedure" in Access that handles it.

Comment: @Mat's and Comintern - I think we're in more agreement than it sounds like above.  I routinely separate the data transformation (ETL) from the analysis - it's just that I do them in the same Access DB.  I import the source data unedited (which maintains an audit trail).  I have one or more queries to transform the data to something useful.  These steps are frequently stored in a macro if there are more than one - the "stored procedures" you mentioned.  Then I do the analysis on the good data.  (continued)

Comment: (part 2) The question asked was whether the data transformation should be SQL or VBA - in this case, a simple query met the requirement so VBA isn't necessary, and I prefer queries to VBA functions when they will do the job.  In cases where the same source data is used in multiple apps, I do the ETL step in one db and link to the resulting tables in each app.  When the data is unique to one app, I keep the ETL with the analysis for simplicity.

Comment: @DonGeorge makes sense. I guess it's just Access' limited tooling that makes it feel a bit awkward, at least if you're coming from SQL Server. Though, OP also says he's looking for "the right way" to do things ;-)

Comment: @DonGeorge and Mat's Mug - Fantastic stuff guys. Pretty much where I was headed (though it may not seem like it from the post) but it has been tremendously valuable to get everyone's perspective. Summarizing the comments above, the key that I gather is to separate the ETL from housing/analyzing the data to keep things clean and efficient. The ETL can be performed in different ways - including a VBA script, SQL queries, or in a separate, purpose-designed database. Access is, of course, probably not the best tool for the job, but it is what I have to work with at my client, so thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into Union queries - that's what I use when I need to convert matrix data to rows.  Something like

```
Select location, "Jan" as month, [jan] as [submission date] from [data table]

union all select location, "Feb", feb from [data table]

union all select location, "Mar", mar from [data table]
....
```

Once you like what you get, you can use this Union in other queries, including a Make table query if you need to make a normalized table for other purposes.

Comment: See, that is exactly what I had tried after having done my initial research. After trying to run the query it gave me a prompt to enter a parameter value, and from the tiny bit of Access experience I have from the past I normally ran into that when I had overlooked something in my query or the way I built out the relationships. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Please post what you tried.  If it's asking for a parameter value, you may have misspelled or mispunctuated a field name, but I cannot tell without seeing the code.  Include the table structure if it's not exactly what you posted above, too.  Also, what is the parameter it is asking for?  That should give you a good clue as to the error in the query.

Comment: That was exactly it! I had accidentally used a period instead of an underscore in one of the field names. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad it worked.  If this helped, can you please accept the answer?  Thanks

Comment: Its usually better to use Tableau's built in Union feature than to write custom SQL. That allows Tableau to optimize the SQL it sends to the source. If you write custom SQL, Tableau can't optimize it, but uses your SQL as a subquery.

Comment: @ Alex Baklemore - I was told by our Tableau expert that it is generally better to do processing in your database and let Tableau just mess with the view-specific queries after the fact, since we would want to minimize processing overhead as the data is explored in Tableau. Seemed to make sense, since Tableau seems more of a dashboarding rather than number-crunching tool. Do you disagree, or am I misunderstanding something from your response? Unless Tableau works differently than how I think and is actually running the SQL written in access every time it needs the info it is pulling.

Comment: @jemmell - my understanding is that you'll want to feed the data to Tableau as cleanly as possible. Do all your ETL, then let Tableau chew on the results, don't have it do the ETL for you.

Comment: @FreeMan - Definitely agree that Tableau shouldn't be doing the ETL, but that isn't what I had asked in the last comment. I am asking whether queries/calculations should be written in Access or Tableau, and my conclusion had been to do as much in Access as possible.